# min and max simply doesn't work in this case?

Tags: c++

So here's the code which works. Posted it without any changes.
There is X and Y values which must be betwen 0 and 1024. tyleSize is 1024;

//for X

```
int loffx=accurate(curphisobj->x) + (rand() % 100) - 50; //some math, doent matter
loffx=max(loffx,1);
loffx=min(loffx,tyleSize);
```

//for Y

```
int loffy=accurate(curphisobj->y) + (rand() % 100) - 50;
loffy=max(loffy,1);
loffy=min(loffy,tyleSize-3);
```

But if I write it like this:

```
int loffy=min(max(accurate(curphisobj->y) + (rand() % 100) - 50,1),tyleSize - 2);
int loffx=min(max(accurate(curphisobj->x) + (rand() % 100) - 50,0),tyleSize);
```

I get loffx and loffy 1034, 1029, -5, - 2, all kinds of nombers uncut by max and min.

Is there something i dont know about C++ compiler, or there's some dumb mistake?

Comment: definition of `max` and `min`, also `accurate` and what are you trying to do?.. Any namespaces you are `using`, any files `#include`d?..

Comment: Do you need a clamper function?

Comment: signedness of the types whose declaration is not shown?  are these `std::min` and `std::max`?

Comment: In the first example you say `tileSize - 3`, but then further down you have changed it to `tyleSize - 2`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Not a typo. I pick a random pixel and use 256 pixels from its position. So if y=1023 and x 1000 for example I will get outside of picture. So I remove some, but 2 or 3 doesnt matter.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you're actually using the `min` and `max` functions from `<algorithm>`, and not some macros defined elsewhere. For instance, the Windows header [`windef.h`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143208) defines `max` like this:

```
#define max(a,b)  (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

This won't work in your code because it potentially evaluates each argument twice, and `rand` by design returns a different result each time.

Try viewing the source after preprocessing to see if you're using the macros. You can turn off the Windows macros by defining `NOMINMAX` before including any headers.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 I upvoted for you. I'll ping you when I need an extra vote. (Not really, psychic debugging powers worthy of upvote.)

Comment: They could also explicitly say `std::min` and `std::max` to be sure of getting the standard library functions.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Well, it gives you a compiler error if the wrong ones are picked anyway

Comment: Also, for a quick check, put parentheses around the `min` and `max` where they're used (i.e,. change `min` to `(min)` and `max` to `(max)`); function-like macros must be followed by `(` as the first non-whitespace character, so the parentheses in effect disable the macros.